# Jupyter notebook load updated package

Tags: python, cmd, jupyter-notebook, package, updates

When I update a basic pack on cmd:

```
pip install --upgrade a=1.0.7
```

But when I run the code:

```
import a
print(a.__version__)
```

outputs:

```
1.0.8
```

It doesn't have any change even if I refresh this notebook unless I reboot. But it will give up all my data in flush. Do you have any method help?

Comment: Do you have more than one Python version?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: Try this `pip uninstall a` then, `pip install a==1.0.7 `.

Answer (score 0):

Does reloading the module help?

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reloading-modules-python/ for info how to do it depending on your python version. Up to date documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload on the python site.